# Aspose ColumnCollection getCount() exact meaning

Tags: java, excel, aspose

Aspose

```
    //Instantiating a Workbook object
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();        
    //Obtaining the reference of the first worksheet
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    ColumnCollection columns = worksheet.getCells().getColumns();
    int count = columns.getCount();
```

1. what is the value of columns.getCount() here meant?   the maximum column count in a worksheet?
2. if I want to know the column count of each row in a worksheet, how to do in aspose? (e.g. row1 has 10 columns, row 2 has 5 columns...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Well, ColumnCollection/RowCollection.getCount() would give you rows/cols count which are initialized in the worksheet, so it may include cells even if they are empty or with null values. I think you should use Cells.getMaxDataRow and Cells.getMaxDataColumn methods to get the farthest (last) row/column indices (zero-based), see the sample code segment for your reference:
e.g

**Sample code:**

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx", new LoadOptions());
//Get the farthest (last) row's index (zero-based) which contains data.
int lastRowIndex = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells().getMaxDataRow();
//Get the farthest (last) column's index (zero-based) which contains data.
int lastColIndex = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells().getMaxDataColumn();
```

2.) You may use Cells.endCellInRow attribute to get the last cell in a row (you may evaluate the column index of the resultant cell). See the sample code.
e.g

**Sample code:**

```
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();     
//Get last cell in the 4th row
Cell lastCellOutput = cells.endCellInRow(3);
//Get the column index of the cell.
int col = lastCellOutput.getColumn();
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

For detailed questions about Aspose APIs, you may [post](https://forum.aspose.com/) here.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.